# C++ library for HTTP requests - XML, JSON, CSV

Tags: c++, http, request

I'm looking for a C++ library that make HTTP requests and turn data from/in XML, JSON, CSV. I'm kinda new to this subject and i really need your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take C libraries that I had been used for example:

- HTTP: [libcurl](http://libcurl.org/)
- XML：[libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)
- JSON：[cjson](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjson)
- CSV：[libcsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv)